# how to change value with repetition less than a specific number to "other" in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that has more than 20 types values in its "S.A" column. I showed a sample of the column below:

```
structure(list(`temp$S.A[1:30]` = c("Yaletown", "Fairview VW", 
"West End VW", "Fairview VW", "Downtown VW", "Hastings", "Yaletown", 
"Main", "Marpole", "West End VW", "Yaletown", "Yaletown", "Kitsilano", 
"Hastings East", "Grandview VE", "Grandview Woodland", "Downtown VW", 
"Downtown VW", "West End VW", "Downtown VE", "West End VW", "West End VW", 
"West End VW", "Yaletown", "Downtown VW", "West End VW", "Downtown VW", 
"West End VW", "Yaletown", "West End VW")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame")
```

if I use `table` function, I get the result shown below which shows all possible values for S.A in my dataframe:

[image]

Now, what I want to do is to **Replace names with repetition less than 100 with "other"**. For example, in the values shown below, "Arbutus" is repeated less than 100 times, so I want to change all "Arbutus" values to "other" in order to reduce the number of variables.
I tried this code to find the names:

```
    aa <- as.data.frame(table(temp$S.A))
    bb <- subset(aa, aa$Freq < 100)
    cc <- bb[1]
```

This helps me to find the names, however, I am not sure how to continue and replace them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue working with what you have you may use -

```
temp$S.A[temp$S.A %in% cc] <- 'Other'
```

to change all the values available in `cc` to `"Other"`.

---

However, `forcats` has a function to do this `fct_lump_min`.

```
temp$S.A <- forcats::fct_lump_min(temp$S.A, 100)
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason, the first method didn't work, but the second one was great! and it worked

Comment: Maybe using `cc <- bb[[1]]` would work.

Comment: @RonakShah I think //tmp// needs to be changed to /temp//